# How to write a query to remove duplicate rows?

Tags: t-sql, uniqueidentifier

I'm using SSMS 2008R2, and I have a table that has 2 uniqueidentifier columns which are mirror images of each other.  How do I remove the duplicate rows?

e.g. I have a table with the following:

```
ColA      ColB       ColC       ColD
ABCD      EFGH       4          5
EFGH      ABCD       5          4
```

So ColA and ColB are the two uniqueidentifier columns, whereas ColC and ColD belong to ColA and ColB.  So if I broke this down into separate events, this would look like:

```
ABCD -> 4
EFGH -> 5
```

How can I list all of this information on just one line instead of two?
This is what I want the above to look like instead:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD
ABCD    4       EFGH    5
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to _remove_, i.e. `delete`, anything, nor are there duplicate rows involved. Could you rephrase the title to be a smidge more accurate?

Comment: Your edit makes no sense. You want to swap the contents of `ColB` and `ColC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just hide the differences between rows with them remaining mostly untouched, you could do this (sorting your columns so they are in the same order, allowing duplicates to be hidden with `DISTINCT`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   t2.*
FROM
   dbo.YourTable t
   CROSS APPLY (
       SELECT t.ColA, t.ColB, t.ColC, t.ColD WHERE t.ColA <= t.ColB
       -- Note: this next SELECT has the columns in a different order!
       UNION ALL SELECT t.ColB, t.ColA, t.ColD, t.ColC WHERE t.ColA > t.ColB
   ) t2
;
```

This will not work correctly if `ColA` or `ColB` can have `NULL` values.

But it seems like you want to do a multi-column unpivot, where ColA and ColC's relationship doesn't have any particular relationship to ColB and ColC (aside from perhaps some key columns, which could be included as needed), something like this:

```
SELECT -- can do DISTINCT if you remove the Type column
   c.Type,
   c.Code,
   c.Value
FROM
   dbo.YourTable t
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT 'ColA', t.ColA, t.ColC
      UNION ALL SELECT 'ColB', t.ColB, t.ColD
   ) c (Type, Code, Value)
;
```

You don't have to put the `Type` column in, but I thought it would be useful for you to see how adding it can help keep your data's meaning when normalized properly.

Without more information about your data and what you're trying to accomplish, I can't offer more guidance.

I would opine that if you're storing independent events in multiple columns, then the database design is suboptimal and needs to be normalized--this data should be stored in rows, not columns, as my second query transforms the data to.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but actually I'm trying to get all of this information on just one line.  I will update my description now to show you what I mean

Comment: when i ran your second query above, it gave me each row separately instead of removing duplicates.

Comment: Did you try the first query? It does give one line ... ?

Comment: You're right, the second one gives two lines, one for each code (but it does not show each code twice). Given the vagueness of the question it was one of my guesses as to what you wanted. However, I believe that my first query *will* provide what you need, as long as you implement it correctly and notice that the two lines inside the `CROSS APPLY` have their column references in a different order.

Comment: Also, depending on your data (I have no clue what the real data is because you've obscured it), you could use the second query, then `PIVOT`--this might work better if you're actually dealing with many more than two columns needing detection as identical (but in that case, your question needs updating to indicate this). If there really are only two (sets) of columns that need to be compared, what I showed in my first query will work grandly.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I think that your first query does it if I order the columns correctly!

Comment: Any chance you could delete the comment about not responding?